# How to run the same JS script in one HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS script that opens a modal dialog window when you click on a certain HTML element.

My problem is that the script only works for one element. When I call the same class name `.trigger` on another element, the entire script fails to work.

HTML

```
<div class="trigger">
   <h2>Contact Me Form</h2>
      <div class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <span class="close-button">x</span>
              <p>Contact form details goes here</p>   
          </div>
       </div>
</div>

<div class="trigger">
   <h2>About Me</h2>
      <div class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <span class="close-button">x</span>
              <p>About Me details goes here</p>   
          </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
          var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
          var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
          var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button"); 

          function toggleModal() {
              modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
          }

          function windowOnClick(event) {
              if (event.target === modal) {
                  toggleModal();
              }
              else if (event.target === closeButton) {
                toggleModal();
              }
          }

          trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
          closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
          window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

edit:
I tried to change my JS code and it still doesn't work:

````
          var modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
          const triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
          var closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".close-button"); 

        for (const trigger of triggers) {
             trigger.addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
          }

          function toggleModal(event)
            event.target.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle("show-modal");
          }

          function windowOnClick(event) {
              if (event.target === modal) {
                  toggleModal();
              }
              else if (event.target === closeButton) {
                toggleModal();
              }
          }


          closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
          window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
    ```
````

Comment: `var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");` selects **only the first** `.modal` in the document. Use `const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');` and then iterate over the list that gets you.

Comment: @connexo I tried changing it to querySelectorAll and it doesn't work

Comment: Your `function toggleModal(event)
            event.target.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle("show-modal");
          }
` is missing an opening `{`.

Answer (score 3):

`var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");` selects **only the first** `.modal` in the document. Use `const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');` and then iterate over the `NodeList` you get from that.

Like this:

```
const triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');

for (const trigger of triggers) {
  trigger.addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
}

function toggleModal(event) {
  event.target.closest('.trigger').querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle("show-modal");
}
```

This would be the window click listener:

```
// get the modals and make an array from the NodeList
// so we can use array methods on the list
const modals = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.modal'));
function windowOnClick(event) {
  // check if the clicked element is a modal, or in a modal
  if (modals.some((modal) => modal.contains(event.target))) {
    toggleModal();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok please bare with me as I'm sorta new with JS.
I added your revisions to my code and it still doesn't work! Am I doing anything wrong?
Please see my edit above and what I tried to change

Comment: That was just one part of your code re-written. Use this as a starting point and try to deeply inhale what's going on in this. When you've grabbed that, you can easily re-write the rest by yourself.

Comment: Hmm I still can't figure it out. Here is my fiddle. I added my thought process in comments http://jsfiddle.net/r4906skh/1/

Comment: `function toggleModal(event) {
  event.target.closest('.trigger').querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle("show-modal");
}`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript always runs on the entire HTML page. The reason why this is not working is that `document.querySelector(".class-name")` only selects the first element of that class.

Edit: I just saw your comment on your question. Sorry I cannot make comments because I don't have 50 reputations yet. `querySelectorAll` selects all elements and returns an array. You have to iterate through the array and perform whatever you want to do to each element in the array with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Within the function `windowOnClick(event)` you could add more conditional statements within the `if`.

For example:

```
if(event.target == modal || event.target == trigger) {

   //do stuff
}
```

Then for the `toggleModal()` function, you could pass an argument along side with it, to add the class to the right element.

```
function toggleModal(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("show-modal");


}
```

Another way to approach this is using a `switch` statement, if the above doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use select by `Id`?

```
<div Id="1" class="trigger">
```

Or in Jquery:

```
$( ".trigger" ).first().
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying to use this setup in shopify https://shopify.dev/tutorials/customize-theme-add-size-chart

But we also already utilize the same modal and want to have 2 guides on the page.

But when adding 2 the last pop up content shows for the first trigger.

Any insights on how to use this setup and have multiple pop ups and triggers on the page